# Python - How to re-enter input with an exception using multiple-variables?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

pretty new to python and was wondering how I can let the user re-enter their input of multiple variable without making them go through the whole loop if they put in a negative number?
This is what I have so far.

```
while True:
    try:
        length = float(input("Length of the room in feet?\n").strip())
        if length < 0: raise Exception
        width = float(input("Width of the room in feet?\n").strip())
        if width < 0: raise Exception
        height = float(input("Height of the room in feet?\n").strip())
        if height < 0: raise Exception
        break
    except Exception:
        print("The number must be at least 0ft! Please try again.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please print numerical values only! (grater than 0)")
```

So for example, if they input height correctly, but put a negative value for width, they would have to re-enter the height variable again. Is the only way to fix this by using one while loop for each variable?

Answer (score 0):

```py
inputLength = False
inputWidth = False
inputHeight = False

while True:
    try:
        if not inputLength:
            length = float(input("Length of the room in feet?\n").strip())
            if length < 0:
                raise Exception
            else:
                inputLength = True
        if not inputWidth:
            width = float(input("Width of the room in feet?\n").strip())
            if width < 0:
                raise Exception
            else:
                inputWidth = True
        if not inputHeight:
            height = float(input("Height of the room in feet?\n").strip())
            if height < 0:
                raise Exception
            else:
                inputHeight = True
        break
    except Exception:
        print("The number must be at least 0ft! Please try again.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please print numerical values only! (grater than 0)")
```

I use three bool value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the values at the end of code and raise the exception, like this

```
while True:
    try:
        length = float(input("Length of the room in feet?\n").strip())
        width = float(input("Width of the room in feet?\n").strip())
        height = float(input("Height of the room in feet?\n").strip())

        if (length < 0 or height < 0 or width < 0): 
            raise Exception
        else:
            break
    except Exception:
        print("The number must be at least 0ft! Please try again.")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please print numerical values only! (grater than 0)")
```

what this code does is, it checks for any value is less than 0, else it asks for all three variables values again, is this what you want?